# release version of app throwing c1083 cannot open include file error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, qt4, visual-c++-2008

I have a project that I have been running in debug mode and compiles and works fine.  However, when I try and do a release version I now get the following error:

```
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
 file: 'QtCore/qchar.h': No such file or directory   
 f:\testing_dev\repo\hello_test\Qt\4.6.0\src\corelib\tools\qstring.h 
 45 HelloWorld"
```

I am wondering why it works in debug but not in release and how to remedy it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler settings are different for each build configuration.

You have probably set the Additional Include Directories setting in the Project Properties for the Debug configuration but not for the Release configuration.